# how to execute the rest of the batch after exception thrown during the progress

Tags: mysql

I am trying to have batch process a number of insert queries by using addbatch.
During the execute, it throws out the exception at the first query which causes the exception

However the rest of batch will not be processed. What would be the best approach to handle this matter? If using rollback and isolate the error query before reprogress, it may repeat the same situation at the next error query. It will be very inefficient, particularly if the batch insert volume is huge.
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to surround you first query with an try catch block and duck the exception. Although I suggest it is not a best coding practice. When you have list of insert statements to be executed always we need to take care that the whole got executed successfully or none of the operation got successeded.In addition as per your business scenario you have have a look at batch SKIP and RESTART ability if it works for you